# Estimate for Weierstrass M-Test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to show uniform convergence in order to interchange limit and sum, therefore I have to get an upper bound $M_k$ for

$\displaystyle \left | \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} \frac{k!}{(ct)^k} \exp\large (-\frac{1}{2}t^{-\gamma}\large ) \right |$ for $, c\in(0,1),\gamma\in(1,2)$ and $k\in\mathbb{N_0}$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed.

Note that $t\in(0,\infty)$ can vary and for a bound $M_k$ it must hold that $f_k(t)\le M_k$ for all $t$.

where $\sum_k M_k <\infty$.

I tried a lot, but can not obtain such a bound.

Comment: you can use Stirling's formula to estimate the factorials, the rest will follow easily.

Comment: @Hayk Stirling formular gives an asymptotical approximation, which I could only employ if I already have the $M_k$. The problem is, I can't.

Comment: even without Stirling, you can estimate $$ \frac{k!}{(2k)!} = \frac{1}{(k+1)...(2k)} < \frac{1}{k^k} .$$ Although this estimate is crude, it is nevertheless enough to take care of the rest of the terms.

Comment: Are you aware that $t\in(0,\infty)$ and that a bound it has to hold that $f_k(t)\le M_k, \forall t$? We don't have at all that $t$ is fixed here. It is $x,c,\gamma$ fixed, but nothing else.

Comment: Made an edit, it was not clear, sorry.